# Using Regex to identify Entity on a Google Action Intent

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder, nlu

I have this Intent on Google Actions with a couple of utterances:

[image]

and I'm using one of the default system types:

[image]

The Bank Account should always be 8 digits so I was thinking if I could use Regex on Google Actions to identify this exact entity when typed by the user.

If yes, how exactly?

Can I just create an utterance with Regex like this: `\d{8}`

Should I "highlight" as Parameter just like I did with the two given examples as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

While this is not visible in the Actions Console, it is something that can be done if you download the project to a local environment using [gactions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions).

You can create a new [`Type`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Type) in under `custom/types`. You will use create [RegularExpression Entities](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/RegularExpressionType).

```yaml
regularExpression:
    entities:
        # `bankNumber` is your parameter name. It can be custom.
        bankNumber:
            regularExpressions:
                - \d{8} # In the `re2` syntax
```

Then you'll need to re-upload your project to the Actions Console with `gactions push` and `gactions deploy preview`.

Comment: That's an interesting approach Nick, I'm using Jovo 4 (I don't know if you ever heard of it) so I'll try and let you know how it works (but first I'll have to figure out how to do that on Jovo)

Comment: I've heard of Jovo, but haven't used it.